# How to stop certreq from showing dialog box for choosing Certification Authority?

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, certificate-authority

I am submitting a new Certificate Signing Request to the Root CA using the command

```
certreq -submit ".\certsignrequest.req"
```

but the dialog box to choose the Certification Authority keeps showing up. The other post that I've found so far is only applicable for a domain-joined computer

I've tried to use the -config option but I'm unable to get it to work on a standalone, non-domain joined CA. What should I type for the -config option?

[image: Image for certca popup]

Answer (score 0):

certreq requires requires kerberos (joining the domain) to authenticate with the CA, unless you have the ADCS CES/CEP [Enrollment Web Services](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/098f858a-3e89-48d2-828e-274487033f6b/how-to-request-certificate-from-a-nondomain-computer?forum=winserversecurity) running in your environment.

I find it's much easier to copy the CSR to a device that *is* on the domain, sign it, and copy the certificate back to the off-domain device. It's pretty common to do for appliances that require uploading a certificate too.

---

Like you mention in your question, you can specify the CA to use with the `-Config` parameter when on the domain. The format should be `Computer`\`CA` using the names from the prompt in your screenshot like:

```
certreq -submit -config 'MyCA.domain.com\CertificateAuthorityName' $Path $Outfile
```

Comment: I am planning to use both a Standalone Root CA, as well as a Standalone Subordinate CA, both of which are non domain joined. In this case, what would the -config parameter be for me if i want to specify the Root CA as part of the command line argument for certreq?

Comment: @bellydrum If you have the web services set up, you can use the configured web url, usually something like `-config https://MyCA.domain.com/certsrv`.

Comment: Also, what is the case where you use an active directory certificate authority server, and don't use active directory? It just seems like something that OpenSSL might handle better for you.

Comment: Unfortunately due to some requirements, I cannot use OpenSSL, and also am not able to use web servuices as well.